# How to link to Twitter, Facebook, and YouTube Apps from within another mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, twitter, cordova

I know I've seen other apps do this (at least on iOS), but I'm not sure how it can be done.

Is there any way (a protocol or url scheme perhaps) to open the Twitter, Facebook, and YouTube apps from within another app?

I'm building a phonegap app and publishing for iOS, Android, and BlackBerry (eventually Windows Mobile as well, but that's down the road). I assume the respective apps would have to be installed on the device first in order for it to work in the first place.

I have a client who really wants this feature added to his app, but I just can't seem to find how it can be done.

I noticed this: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes and even tried it on a test app with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can call startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("youtube url"))); for youtube

Comment: That looks like it would be code for Android (Java I assume)... Would I put that in the activity? And how would I integrate that with PhoneGap as 99.9% of my code is HTML/CSS/JavaScript (and PHP on the server side).

Comment: I am not familar with phonegap, if there is no way to launch app for all os version, you can implement for each: it works like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603913/can-we-connect-phonegap-api-application-with-pure-native-applicationobj-c-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is Android specific but if you want to do Twitter look at this tutorial:

http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt5p1

For YouTube you can use my VideoPlayer plugin which can now handle YouTube video's:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html

and finally Dave Johnson did some Facebook integration as well:

https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as accepted as it was the most accurate to answering my question. While your answer was Android specific, it at least got me going in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For example on iOS you can open facebook by

```
-(IBAction) openFB{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://friends"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

But make sure you have facebook app installed, you can also test it by trying to open **fb://friends** in Safari, and it will take you to Facebook

Comment: OK I think this might be useful for iOS, and @tabbykitten commented above a way to do so in Android... For this part of iOS code, would I put that in my AppDelegate.m under -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType ??

Comment: Put it in the IBAction outlet of the view, and then associate the IBAction with the button on the Nib, I have edited my answer

Comment: I am using Phonegap and 99.9% of my code for the app is in HTML/CSS/JavaScript so all of my "view" content (including all input methods) are WebView based as that is what Phonegap ties into on the native-code side of things to allow for programming in web-based languages. So tying it to an IBAction outlet would work in this case.

Comment: I didnt quite understood.. You need an option to make it work with phonegap or you are ok using the ibaction?

Comment: I need an option that works with phonegap as my interface does not have any ibactions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I can use this as part of an iOS plugin for PhoneGap. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

fb: needs to be registered system side. That's the case for a few apps or for a few URLs (maps.google.com for example). There is no generic way to load an app from a link, from an app or mobile web.

Comment: That makes sense... So the only way for that to be registered is by the app that it would refer to? (i.e. Facebook app would register fb: when installed). Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate the explanation/clarification regarding how the protocols/url-schemes must be registered by the app it would refer too.